# What is the fastest way to do Cholesky decomposition in R?

Tags: r, matrix, rcpp

In `R`, I would like to perform a Cholesky Decomposition on a huge positive definite covariance/correlation matrix. An example is the following where I have constructed a mock positive definite matrix

```
N <- 3000
amat <- matrix(rnorm(N*N), N, N) 
A <- amat %*% t(amat)  # A is PD 

system.time(chol(A))
user  system elapsed 
4.390   0.023   4.440
```

I am using the `chol()` function above, standard in `R` and it takes over 4 seconds. The problem with this is I need to iterate over something like that 50,000 times and so the time adds up very quickly.

Does anyone know of the fastest way in `R` or perhaps using `Rcpp` to do this? Thanks!

Comment: In dense-world this should be as fast as it gets (using Lapack). I'm not much of an R-user and don't know what kind of BLAS/LAPACK setup is done: maybe it pays off to switch to Intel's MKL or other alternatives (if that's possible).

Comment: Which processor specification are you running?

Comment: I have access to 64 core units and also GPU's, thanks!

Comment: There is no gain from Rcpp here -- everything is done in external LAPACK/BLAS libraries for both R and Rcpp. GPUs can be faster, but often are not as the 'transport cost' is high too and may not get amortised.  Benchmark and profile ...

Comment: Did you try doing it in Microsoft R?It does multi-threading

Comment: @There are some packages in are to perform matrix operations on GPU, if you program the decomposition from scratch in those packages might be faster.

Comment: What BLAS/LAPACK are you using? With OpenBLAS on my dual core laptop using four threads this takes 0.2 seconds!

Comment: There is no magic in Microsoft R; it simply contains the MKL--which you can also install for standard R, or use OpenBLAS, or ...   Many choices.  But the main thing stands: it is your library, not your R code, which will matter here.